# web chat plugin "fade" class messes with other bootstrap components

Tags: jquery, web, applozic

I am using applozic web chat plugin for web chat window. The problem i am facing is, the script messes with modal and component load with ajax call. The plugin script adds automatically fade class.

I believe, github.com has an open issue relate to this.
https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Web-Plugin/issues/290

please suggest any workaround or update the code base to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The workaround which I'm using currently is that I have set properties as an important tags on element which were messing things around.

Just add these properties in your css file.

```
.fade
{ opacity:1 !important; }

.modal-backdrop.show 
{ opacity: 0.5 !important; }
```